# ¿como paso un array de numeros diferentes, a organizarlos de menor a mayor y de mayor a menor con javaScript sin metodos?

Tags: javascript

Tengo esto pero al último me devuelve un objeto con dos array identicos.

asi:  `{as: [8,7,7,6,5] de: [8,7,7,6,5]}` cuando uso las funciones por separado funcionan bien.

Y pues lo que tiene que hacer es un solo objeto: `{as: [5,6,7,7,8] de: [8,7,7,6,5]}`

```js
let array = [7, 5, 7, 8, 6];
const ascendente = (arra) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arra.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arra.length; j++) {
      if (arra[j] > arra[j + 1]) {
        let aux = arra[j];
        arra[j] = arra[j + 1];
        arra[j + 1] = aux;
      }
    }
  }
  return arra;
};

const descendente = (arra) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arra.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arra.length; j++) {
      if (arra[j] < arra[j + 1]) {
        let aux = arra[j];
        arra[j] = arra[j + 1];
        arra[j + 1] = aux;
      }
    }
  }
  return arra;
};

console.log(ascendente(array))
console.log(descendente(array))

function unirlos(a){
    let as = ascendente(a);
    let de = descendente(a);
    console.log({as, de});
}
unirlos(array)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cada vez que ordenas modificas el array original, es decir en todo tu código existe un solo array. Esto es porque los array se guardan por referencia a un espacio en memoria, y todo lo tuyo apunta al mismo espacio.

Tiene que crear una copia del array en cada función, puedes ocupar [structuredClone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone)

```js
let array = [7, 5, 7, 8, 6];
const ascendente = (lista) => {
  let arra = structuredClone(lista);
  for (let i = 0; i < arra.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arra.length; j++) {
      if (arra[j] > arra[j + 1]) {
        let aux = arra[j];
        arra[j] = arra[j + 1];
        arra[j + 1] = aux;
      }
    }
  }
  return arra;
};

const descendente = (lista) => {
  let arra = structuredClone(lista);
  for (let i = 0; i < arra.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arra.length; j++) {
      if (arra[j] < arra[j + 1]) {
        let aux = arra[j];
        arra[j] = arra[j + 1];
        arra[j + 1] = aux;
      }
    }
  }
  return arra;
};

console.log(ascendente(array))
console.log(descendente(array))

function unirlos(a){
    let as = ascendente(a);
    let de = descendente(a);
    console.log({as, de});
}
unirlos(array)
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que en la función `unirlos()` estás utilizando el array original `array` en las dos funciones y sucede que en ambas funciones están modificando el mismo array y terminas con el mismo resultado en ambas variables. Lo puedes solucionar sacando una copia al array utilizando el [**operador spread `[...]`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), quedando tu función `unirlos()` así:

```
function unirlos(a) {
  let as = ascendente([...a]);
  let de = descendente([...a]);
  console.log({ as, de });
}
```

Tu código final sería el siguiente:

```js
let array = [7, 5, 7, 8, 6];

const ascendente = arra => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arra.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arra.length; j++) {
      if (arra[j] > arra[j + 1]) {
        let aux = arra[j];
        arra[j] = arra[j + 1];
        arra[j + 1] = aux;
      }
    }
  }
  return arra;
};

const descendente = arra => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arra.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arra.length; j++) {
      if (arra[j] < arra[j + 1]) {
        let aux = arra[j];
        arra[j] = arra[j + 1];
        arra[j + 1] = aux;
      }
    }
  }
  return arra;
};

console.log(ascendente(array));
console.log(descendente(array));

function unirlos(a) {
  let as = ascendente([...a]);
  let de = descendente([...a]);
  console.log({ as, de });
}

unirlos(array);
```